# Should I get a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to buy a small cheap computer to host servers whether it be game servers or something I program (I do a lot of networked projects). Is the Raspberry Pi a good option?

P.S: Obviously, I don't expect/need the computer to be very powerful.

Comment: so much for 'Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct. '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I have five. One decoding ADS-B aircraft transmissions via a DVB dongle, another running a syslog server, and the others running motioneye os as security cameras. I have learnt more about linux with these than any other device. Make sure that they are all powered with a good microusb power source 5v 2amp minimum - The Pi3 requires 5v 3amp if you use it as a desktop computer. If you like tinkering, its the best starter kit out there. Always buy cases as they are very static sensitive. Always get class 10 SD cards. You will not regret getting one or a few.